# How to convert data from XML format into Excel workbook or database table

Tags: import, xml

I have some data that is given in a consistent XML format (which I can't change). I would like to import it into a database so that I can work with it, and then search, identify and export certain records into an Excel workbook, as I don't think it can be imported to Excel directly.

I have no experience working with databases so I'm not sure if this is possible or for the best approach. My question is: **Can this be done with a database tool/function?** It's not important what the database system is, but I would prefer MS-Access or SQL-Server Express.

Comment: Excel can natively import XML. http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/import-xml-data-HP010206405.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Excel is capable of importing XML directly.

See [this link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/import-xml-data-HP010206405.aspx) for details.